# Full Text search and Subqueries in the FROM Clause

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

When i try the following query:

```
select co_id, Match(co_title,co_description,co_text) AGAINST ('word')  from (select * from content limit 100)co
```

the result is:  **#1191 -Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list**

FULLTEXT indexes are set correctly :

when i try :

> select co_id, Match(co_title,co_description,co_text) AGAINST ('word')  from content

it works fine.

why the first query is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not about `FULLTEXT` only, actually - that is because you're referring to subquery (in `FROM` clause) which is runtime-created table (rowset) and have not any indexes, so FULLTEXT also as well.

I suggest this:

```
SELECT 
  co_id, 
  MATCH(co_title,co_description,co_text) AGAINST ('word') 
FROM 
  content 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: in this case,  i'm running a fulltext search on all rows then i'm extracting the first 100 rows. am i right? 
My point is not to search in all content table (my content table is huge).
is this possible?

Comment: When using `LIMIT` - it's not fully equal to `FULL SCAN`, especially if it's about selecting _first N rows_. In this case DBMS will read & return only that N rows, which will be quick - despite of FULL SCAN execution plan